# How to retrieve number of session from mobile device and non-mobile device from Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

I want to get number of session from mobile device and non-mobile device in Yes/No format like:

```
Mobile Device    Count
  Yes             150
  No              670
```

I tried using metric "ga:sessions" and dimension "ga:deviceCategory". But it's showing data for mobile,desktop,tablet etc.

I heard about custom dimensions but I don't know about its use. Can someone please help me on this. I am working on Google Analytics for first time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use segments to isolate your data.

Segments let you isolate and analyze subsets of your Analytics data. You use the Segment builder to configure the individual filters that together constitute a Segment. You then apply Segments to your reports and dashboards so you can see that specific data.

Here are a few helpful default segments Google provides:

Mobile Traffic
Mobile and Tablet Traffic
Tablet Traffic
Tablet and Desktop Traffic

More on segments: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en